# Database "updated_at" always changed to time of "git push heroku"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a Rails 3.2.9 app on Heroku.

For some odd reason in one of my tables whenever I push a new code version to Heroku the database lines are all updated at the same time, which I know from using Adminium to look at the Postgres database's "updated_at" columns.

What could be causing this?

What part of a Rails app could be doing this? Where should I look to debug this?

Comment: This is bizarre sounding. Does this happen to all of the tables in your database? What if you use the heroku run console and then look at a specific record (Like User.first.updated_at)? Does it show the same as Adminium? Perhaps it is an Adminium issue, displaying the wrong value for some reason.

Comment: No, actually it's definietly not an Adminium thing. Is there any way to track what has changed in a record? I am using Postgres database...

Comment: *shot in the dark* Have you got any database triggers setup?

Comment: I don't event know what "database triggers" are…?

Comment: show your schema that relates to that column